# Pandas datetime column operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe that look like this.

```
| Date_Time           | Execution_Time |  
|---------------------|----------------|  
| 2019-10-10 09:07:29 | 14.0           |
| 2019-09-21 19:47:01 | 14.3           |
| 2019-09-19 02:49:49 | 14.1           |
| 2019-09-27 23:19:16 | 21.9           |
| 2019-09-05 18:46:00 | 14.2           |
```

The execution is in seconds. How can I add `Date_Time` and `Execution_Time` ?

datatype for **Date_Time**: `object`,
             **Execution_Time**: `float64`

I have tried `df['diff'] = df['Date_Time'] + df['Execution_Time']`
and it returns following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First column convert to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and second to timedeltas by 
[`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['diff'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time']) + 
              pd.to_timedelta(df['Execution_Time'], unit='s'))
print (df)
             Date_Time  Execution_Time                    diff
0  2019-10-10 09:07:29            14.0 2019-10-10 09:07:43.000
1  2019-09-21 19:47:01            14.3 2019-09-21 19:47:15.300
2  2019-09-19 02:49:49            14.1 2019-09-19 02:50:03.100
3  2019-09-27 23:19:16            21.9 2019-09-27 23:19:37.900
4  2019-09-05 18:46:00            14.2 2019-09-05 18:46:14.200
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me. previously i tried
`newdf[["Date_Time","Execution_Time"]] = newdf[["Date_Time","Execution_Time"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)` to convert both to date time.. but the 'Execution_time' Column value got messed up.. Thank you again